# PHPMailer not Working in my server but another server its work fine

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer

This code works in my server(1) .But when i upload same code in my another server its not working
i was try comment / Without Comment  '#main-> isSMTP() and' 
but still not working

```
<?php 
    require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    // $mail->isSMPT();
    $mail->Host="smtp.gamil.com";

    $mail->SMTPAuth=true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure="ssl";
    $mail->port=465;
    $mail->Username="myaccount@gamil.com";
    $mail->Password="validPassword";

    $mail->setFrom("m.n.u.yea.hia.khan@gamil.com","Nasir Khan");
    $mail->addAddress('nasirkhan.webdev@gmail.com');
    $mail->addReplyTo('m.n.u.yea.hia.khan@gamil.com');
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->Subject="this is subject";
    $mail->Body="<h1>Email Body</h1>";

    if(!$mail->send()){
    echo "not send";
    }else{
    echo "send";
    }

?>
```

When i user '$mail->isSMPT()' page do not load and  no message echo

when i do not use '$mail->isSMPT()' page lode and show message 'not send'

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo that is a fatal error: There is no such method as `isSMPT()`; the method you are looking for is `isSMTP()`.

You are running an old version of PHPMailer, you have not based your code on [the gmail example provided](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/gmail.phps), and you have no error checking, so you have no error messages to look at. Once you fix those things, you may still have problems, in which case you should read [the troubleshooting guide](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting) and search for the error messages that you see.